# Why can't I stop a while loop by calling the function it's in with a parameter that makes the statement false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

As the title suggests, why can't I stop a while loop by calling the function it is in with a parameter that makes the while statement false, like this?:

```
def toggleLogger(isToggled):
    while isToggled: 
        if(keyboard.read_key() == "esc"):
            toggleLogger(False)

toggleLogger(True)
```

I did some changes to the code and replaced `toggleLogger(False)` with `break` which basically solved my little problem, but it really bugs me that it doesn't work. Especially since I don't get any errors. What I don't understand is that `toggleLogger(True)` that starts the script **works**, but not the other one.

Comment: That just executes the function **again**. It doesn't stop the current execution. You need to return, break, or change the value of `isToggled` in the scope of the current function.

Comment: You might want to do some reading about recursion or recursive functions calls, of which this is an example. isToggled will be defined independently in each function call, so the isToggled parameter of the call inside your function has no effect on the value of the isToggled parameter in the first call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're setting `[toggleLogger = false]`, but not the bool to false. 
`[isToggled  = false]`. Your code is checking whether `isToggled == false`, not `toggleLogger`.

if you print `toggleLogger` and `isToggled` before and after you will see the difference.

Try something like:
`isToggled = !isToggled`     or
`isToggled = False`